# Which core is a task running on?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to identify which core a task is running on in the TPL?

Comment: Probably not. It can be moved between cores. And what would be the use?

Comment: thats what i'm thinking but i just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because what if the processor suddenly changes in the middle of the function returning the value?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't **get** the current core that your thread is running on, however you can **set** a thread to run on a specific core.

To **set** thread to a specific cpu or core, you may either use  `System.Threading.Thread.BeginThreadAffinity()` or by get the **processor thread** `System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread` "the OS thread that is running on the processor and represented by .net managed thread", then use `processThread.ProcessorAffinity` "Not that `processThread.ProcessorAffinity` is a **set only** property".

Comment: +1 right. But just a note: I'm not sure if I'd call a thread "physical", since it doesn't have material existence in any way...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Thanks, physical removed from the answer.